# Angular2+ prevent component access with jwt

Tags: angular, jwt

I am about to begin angular4 application, but before I start I am trying to fill gaps and I have concerns.

I will use jwt to get user claims, from .NET Identity, that leads me to thought that all my component access will be based on that user object which is stored clients side.

**Will users be able to gain access to components if they changes payload of jwt from the response?**

Here is brief example of how could it be handled in ASP.NET

```
if(userRoles.Any(u => roles.Contains("admin")){
  //render admin partial
}
```

Comment: If the user changes the payload, the signature of the JWT will not be correct anymore and the JWT decoder will through an error.

Comment: @Ploppy Does that mean that I validate signature against payload on the client side without knowing the secret?

Comment: The server is the one encoding with the secret. The client only decode and check the signature.

Comment: It seems like I am missing somethign about jwt, my assumption was that whenever I post back to the server with a barer header containing my jwt then server can tell that either header or payload has been changed and don't match the signature. 
Can someone point me to dummy guide how is signature being checked against rest part of jwt client side

Comment: [This is a good guide](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

Comment: I not sure but I may have misunderstood your question. I'm investigating too :)

Comment: This is bit of a headache, as all of that stuff is new to me, but I suppose my server is holding secret (private key) and I may assume that signature is public key, from that that would make sense that I can use that to verify header and payload with existing signature without knowing private key, but finding relevant topics with easy answers is quite hard for newcomer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145214/discussion-between-ploppy-and-raimonds).